# How does height of a parachute affect air resistance compared to circumference or diameter?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, drag

I'm trying to find out how much a double in height (making it more ovular or oblong in shape) of the parachute affects air resistance compared to a double in circumference or diameter. Can someone tell me if parachutes with the same circumference (therefore looking the same when looked from the top) but are taller or shorter have different air resistance?

Comment: The extreme example of what you are asking is the [_streamer_ that is used by model rockets](http://www.hobbylinc.com/htm/sfr/sfr861001.htm). This is a "parachute with zero area" yet it effectively slows the rocket's return to earth by the drag created with a flapping ribbon. The flapping creates a large "effective surface". For a conventional parachute, the aspect ratio of the canopy is less important as the design of the canopy discourages flapping.

Comment: I think the sides count as area as the flapping (usually from wind that comes from other directions, or turbulence) folds the ribbon to face the earth, giving it a very unpredictable amount of drag.

Comment: yes - the sideways motion gives the streamer "effective area". The degree of flapping is a function of the speed, among other things. Makes me wonder what the drag r- velocity elationship would be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air resistance or air drag is basically proportional to square of the velocity of the moving    object ,that is, **F=bv^2** since air has turbulent motion where b is the air drag constant.Drag constant depends on the dimensions of the object. So air drag is ***independent of length or volume of object***, rather it ***depends on the surface area of the object***.

The action of the parachute is based on the principle of air resistance. It dramatically lowers your terminal velocity by increasing your air resistance as you fall. It does that by opening out behind you and creating a large surface area of material with a huge amount of drag. Parachutes are designed to reduce your terminal velocity by about 90 percent so you hit the ground at a relatively low speed of maybe 5–6 meters per second (roughly 20 km/h or 12 mph)—ideally, so you can land on your feet and walk away unharmed.

Increasing the height of the parachute hence ***does not affect*** air resistance.
But increasing the circumference of the parachute in turn ***increases the surface area of the parachute and it increases the air drag exerted on the parachute***.

Similarly for parachutes with same circumference, air resistance is ***same***.

Comment: So surface area is the area of the surface being pushed against, not the total surface area (TSA)? I was confused when reading about air resistance as a box falling vertically that is 9m tall, 3m wide and 3m long has more TSA than a box that's 6 m tall and just as wide and long, but I wasn't sure if this increase in area would affect anything.

Comment: Surface area implies the external surface area ,that is,the area of the surface which is in contact with the air opposing its motion. Naturally the 9m tall box has more surface area and experiences more air resistance.

Comment: Is there any way to guess the difference between an increase of width and an increase of height's effect on air resistance? I assume surfaces parallel to the direction the air pushes have a lesser effect than those that are perpendicular (Otherwise, I'd have no clue how pointy tips make aircraft more aerodynamic).

Comment: In general there is no big difference between an increase of width and an increase of height's effect on air resistance.However,surfaces parallel to the direction the air pushes and also the surfaces that are perpendicular both are subjected to same air resistance.It is like friction;a contact force.If you consider a block falling, the parallel surfaces face air resistance like in case of friction and this inhibits the downward motion.On other hand, the surface perpendicular to air flow and facing downwards also feels air drag but air strikes the face,is deflected sideways,not harming motion.